# Bash Script changing the output file for every file

Tags: bash, file, awk, output

I'm trying to use a command on everyfile .log in a folder but I can't understand how to change the output file for every file in the folder.

```
#!/bin/bash
N="0"
for i in "*.log"
do
    echo "Processing $f file..."
    cat $i | grep "test" | awk '/show/ {a = $1} !/show/{print a,$6}' > "log$N.txt"
done
```

How can i increment the counter for log$n.txt?

Comment: `((N++))` or i dunno maybe look up arithmetic in bash would be a good start.

Answer (score 3):

It's bad practice to write shell loops just to process text (see https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice). This is all you need:

```
awk '
    FNR==1  { print "Processing", FILENAME; a=""; close(out); out="log" fileNr++ ".txt" }
    !/test/ { next }
    /show/  { a = $1; next }
    { print a, $6 > out }
' *.log
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/bin/bash
N="0"
for i in *.log
do
    echo "Processing $f file..."
    cat $i | grep "test" | awk '/show/ {a = $1} !/show/{print a,$6}' > "log$N.txt"
    N=$((N+1))
done
```

You need to increment the variable 'N' over every iteration and remove the double-quotes in the for loop