# How can I generate multiple output files for multiple input files in for loop

Tags: bash, for-loop, output

I'm new to bash and I'm writing a "for loop" script to run metagenome sequences from fastqc software. My problem is when building the output file for these multiple sequences, where the ideal would be to have file with variables, such as assembly_ "something" for each sample (assembly_something1; assembly_something2...). However I can not perform this last step, I'm leaving my script below, if anyone can tell me the way to do this, would appreciate. Thanks!

```
#!/bin/bash
cd Metagenomas

set -x

for forward in *R1_001.fastq; do
    prefix="${forward%R1_001.fastq}"
    reverse="${forward%R1_001.fastq}R2_001.fastq"
    echo "$prefix $forward $reverse 12"
    fastqc -1 $forward -2 $reverse -t 15 -o /home/joaopedro-coelho/assembly_"$prefix"
done
```

Comment: Confirm you have the files you think you have in the current working directory. Does `ls -al *R1_001.fastq` list the files you expect? Does the `echo "$prefix $forward $reverse 12"` output what you expect? Your script appears correct, though I can't vouch for the `fastqc -1 $forward -2 $reverse -t 15 -o /home/joaopedro-coelho/assembly_"$prefix"` line. Otherwise, your script **does** produce correct output for `echo "$prefix $forward $reverse 12"` in a directory with `touch {a,b,c}R1_001.fastq` files created.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Bash Script changing the output file for every file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35936374/bash-script-changing-the-output-file-for-every-file)